# Does running a Java jar with java 8 force TLS1.2 by default?

Tags: java, tls1.2

I've written a java application using an API given to me by a vendor, which accesses that vendor's webapp to download files. The vendor's webapp is dropping support for TLS 1.0/1.1 soon and I want to verify that my application will continue to run. The application runs on a CentOS server with Java 8 installed and I keep reading that Java 8 supports TLS1.2 by default, but I'm curious if it actually FORCES applications to use TLS1.2 or if an application can override the default. I do see references to TLSv1 in the API's code that has me concerned.

I don't think there's much I can do, other than ask the vendor to update their API, but I'm just trying to find out if that's even necessary or if I should expect the application to run with TLS 1.2 right now

```
//auth/AuthProxyClient.class

Socket socket = null;
        if (authProxySSLEnabled) {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = this.getSSLSocketFactory(authProxySSLTrustStore, authProxySSLTrustStorePassword, authProxySSLKeyStore, authProxySSLKeyStorePassword, authProxySSLClientAuth, authProxySSLKeyStoreClientKeyAlias, authProxySSLKeyStoreClientKeyPassword);
            socket = factory.createSocket(host, port);
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1"});
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setUseClientMode(true);
            ((SSLSocket)socket).startHandshake();
            this.logSSLSocketInfo((SSLSocket)socket);
        } else {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
        }

//

try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, (SecureRandom)null);
            factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            return factory;
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException var13) {
            this.logException(var13);
            throw new IllegalStateException(var13);
        }
```

I'm expecting (hoping) that the application will utilize TLS1.2 by virtue of running in Java 8 alone, but I don't know if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: You need to *enable* it but not *force* it because **TLS version is negotiated**.

Through 1.2, this is fairly simple. Each endpoint normally supports a *range* of versions and the ClientHello specifies (only) the *highest* version the client supports. The ServerHello responds with the highest version it supports *or* the client max if that is lower, but if the client max is too low for the server (below server min) server aborts the handshake instead, and if the server's selection is too low for the client the client aborts the handshake. 1.3 makes this negotiation more complicated, but since only Java 11 up supports 1.3 I ignore it here.

Thus as long as the client offers "up to" 1.2, the server can and will select 1.2 and it will work. The client does not need to actively prevent using protocols lower than 1.2, although it may if you wish.

The difference between Java 7 and Java 8 is that both *implement* up to 1.2, but j7 client *by default* only offers "up to" 1.0. (Since SSL3 is now broken and prohibited, and Java never implemented SSL2 at all, "up to" 1.0 is the same as "only" 1.0.) You can override this default in the code, and *if using HttpsURLConnection* (which you aren't) you can use sysprop `https.protocols` to change it. **In j8 the default is "up to 1.2"** *or* sysprop `jdk.tls.client.protocols` as stated by Jonathan but **can be overridden** just like j7.

And **the code you posted DOES override.** That code will support *only* TLS 1.0 in either j7 or j8, and as a result will be rejected by a server that insists on 1.2 (or even 1.1). **You need to change that code**, either to explicitly allow 1.2 -- and it's up to you whether to *allow* 1.0 and 1.1 because even if you do the server won't select them -- or to use and not override the default which for j8 will be suitable. `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` gets you the (different) default in either Java version. (`SSLContext.getDefault()` also uses the default but that doesn't allow you to customize keymgr and trustmgr directly, as your code does.)

(For completeness: if you couldn't or can't change the code, a workaround is to interpose some kind of proxy that on one side accepts the outdated and yucky protocol -- 1.0 -- and on the other side relays the data to the real host using the now fashionable protcol -- 1.2. But I don't think you need that.)